# Taglibs in PrimeFaces 3.2

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, taglib

I'm using primefaces 3.2.
project is build with maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

....  

</html>
```

In JSP file i was able to see suggestions for component parameters, I want same in facelest

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean code auto completion?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse, yes i mean auto completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this if you are using Eclipse for Java EE.

Your project is probably missing some facets (Java Server Faces).

This may help you : http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/tasks/add_jsf_facet.html

Answer (score 0):

I've added in pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>            
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version> 
            <configuration>                 
               <additionalProjectFacets>
                  <jst.jsf>2.0</jst.jsf>
               </additionalProjectFacets>
            </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and It work It automatically added faces to eclipse project